# Strange spaces in bound combobox in Visual Studios 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm using VS 2015, VBnet windows form.

The fields of first and last name are set to varchar(15) to eliminate the empty spaces but when running, the names in the combobox have a weird spacing issue. What's wrong?

[image]

---

UPDATE: I've managed to get the text aligned by using a fixed font (eg: courier) but now I still have the trailing spaces in the combo although the SQL is using VARCHAR which is supposed to hide the trailing spaces.

In the FORM_LOAD I tried without trim, which gives me the following result: (has extra spaces after first and last name)

[image]
**

This is the query I use in FORM_LOAD:

```
Me.VINEWOODSTUDIOS_DataSet.tbl_clients.Columns.Add("FullName", GetType(String), "client_id +' ' + client_first_name + client_last_name")
    Me.Tbl_clientsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.VINEWOODSTUDIOS_DataSet.tbl_clients)
    ComboBox_clients.DisplayMember = "FullName"
```

I'm not sure how to implement the TRIM function in the Query. I tried LTRIM and RTRIM but this doesn't help: (example of RTRIM: )

```
Me.VINEWOODSTUDIOS_DataSet.tbl_clients.Columns.Add("FullName", GetType(String), "client_id +' ' + RTRIM(client_first_name) + RTRIM(client_last_name)")
    Me.Tbl_clientsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.VINEWOODSTUDIOS_DataSet.tbl_clients)
    ComboBox_clients.DisplayMember = "FullName"
```

I want the text to look like this:

```
1001 Eran Zadok
1003 Tomer Zakaim
```

etc... not spaces after first and last names.

Comment: You are not using a [_fixed font_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font). Each character takes its own width. Try with a fixed one (e.g. courier) and the problem should vanish. Confirm it and I will post it as an answer.

Comment: Ops I  thought we were on Stack Overflow. I think this question belong to that site more than to this. Probably it will be moved there.

Comment: Yes, this definitely belongs on Stack Overflow, but you'll probably want some more info in the question about how the box is created.

Comment: Ben, it just fills using the Data Bound items. I didn't do any code to it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess: 
you are probably adding the 3 strings for what it is displayed in the `combobox` entries.
The first and the last name are both fixed array of 15 chars. 
This means that the name the 1st element of the array is *Erin* with 11 spaces after: `name[x]="Erin           "`.

I can see that you are not using a [fixed font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font): so each character takes its own width.
Try with a fixed one (e.g. courier) and the problem should vanish.

Now look how it appears with fixed fonts

> ```
> name[x]="Erin           "
> ```

or not

> name[x]="Erin           "

If the fonts of that part of the application are system dependent, this behaviour will appear depending from the choices of each single user.

Comment: Ok, this started help! I used Courier so the first and last name got aligned but the extra spaces after the names still stay... What's next? (There's no place to add image to a comment so here's a link to see a screenshot: http://www.vinewoodstudios.com/vbnet-font)

Comment: You added that _extra spaces_ forcing to 15 the length of your string. Put a name of 15 and there will be not ;). Kidding apart you should scan all your names, memorize the max length and compose your string formatting with that space length (+1). Edit your question add the way you form the string and the desired output as if it was code (it uses fixed fonts).

Comment: I made the database in Sql Server where you must enter a char number in the datatype section or else it will default to 50! So I'm actually not kidding... I don't understand. I am not "forming" the string in VB code... the combo is just filling itself from the dataset which is taking the data from the SQL DB. I think I'm not understanding you.

Comment: Just in case you WEREN'T kidding... no, I didn't add spaces when inputting the names... :-)

Comment: I also read that selecting "VARCHAR" in SQL server, was supposed to eliminate this spacing issue - but it didn't.

Comment: Update you question. Now it is different from how it starts. BTW please put a text example of the output that you want. I think you want trimmed `name surname`.Write the instructions that you use. Add the tag Sql... we are going out of my experience...

Comment: Question updated.
Yes, I want the text to look like this:

1001 Eran Zadok
1003 Tomer Zakaim

etc... no spaces should be after first and last name.